# Phonegap Sqlte:the statement callback raised an exception or statement errorcallback did not return false

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I have a textfield deviceid i am trying to store that value into sqlite db and then trying to retrieve it in other form but i got the error below.This is working fine when i am runing it in the desktop but i got the error while i try to run in phonegap app.

Error Processing SQL:the statement callback raised an exception or statement errorcallback did not return false
New.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            var db,did;
            function onDeviceReady() {
                db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
                db.transaction(createDB, errorCB, successCB);
            }
            function createDB(tx) {
                alert("createDB");
                tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USERIDDETAILS');
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERIDDETAILS (deviceid TEXT NOT NULL)');
            }
            function errorCB(err) {
                alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
                console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
            }
            function successCB() {
                alert("success");
                console.log("success");
            }
            function insertDB(tx) {
                did = $("[name='deviceid']").val();
                var sql='INSERT INTO USERIDDETAILS(deviceid)VALUES(?)';
                tx.executeSql(sql,[did],sucessQueryDB,errorCB);
                console.log(did);
                alert(did);
            }   
            function sucessQueryDB(tx){
                alert("selected");
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS',[],renderList,errorCB); 
            }
            function renderList(tx,results){ 
            alert("rendering");
                var htmlstring='';
                var len=results.rows.length;
                alert("rendered called"+ len);
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    htmlstring += '<li>'+ results.rows.item(i).deviceid+'</li>';
                }   
                $('#resultList').html(htmlstring);
                $('#resultList').listview('refresh');
            }

            function onClick(){
                db.transaction(insertDB,errorCB);
                window.open("new1.html");
            return false;
        }</script>
</head>   
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3> Login </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <form id="myForm">
             <br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid" placeholder="DeviceId"><br>
             <input type="button" class="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="return onClick()">
        </form>

    </div>
```

New1.html:

```
script type="text/javascript">
        var db;
        function loaddb()
        {
            db = window.openDatabase("Watersenz", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 2*1024*1024);
            db.transaction(successCB,errorCB);
            console.log("loaded");
            alert("loaded");
        }
        function errorCB(err) {
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
            alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
            console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
        }
        function successCB() {
            console.log("success");
            alert("success");
        }

        function queryDB(tx){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM USERIDDETAILS',[],renderList1,errorCB);    
            console.log("selected");
            alert("selected");
        }
        function repopulateId(){
            db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);
            console.log("populated");
            alert("populated");
        }
        function renderList1(tx,results){ 
            console.log("rendering");
            alert("rendering");
            var htmlstring='';  
            var len=results.rows.length;
            var did = results.rows.item(0).deviceid;
            $('#deviceid').val(did);
        }</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3> User Profile </h3>
    </div>
    <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        loaddb();
        repopulateId();
        }); 
    </script>
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <form method="post" id="myForm">
             Device Id:<br><input type="text" class="one" name="deviceid" id="deviceid">
             <ul data-role="listview" id="resultList">
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Can any one help me what the issue is.Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Since sqlite calls are async, execution won't wait for the data to be returned by the query.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        loaddb();
        //repopulateId();
        });
```

call **repopulateId()** in success callback of **loaddb()** function.

```
function successCB() {
            console.log("success");
            alert("success");
            repopulateId();
        }
```

Hope this will help

Comment: No.I am getting the same error if  i call it in the successCB also...actually i forgot to mention when i run this in desktop it is working fine when i am trying it in phonegap app in mobile I am getting this error @Naresh Kumar

Comment: @Anusha, probably u need use deviceready event in new1.html also

Comment: I tried using deviceready event also again i am getting same error.@Naresh Kumar

Comment: its hard to find where the problem is can u catch me on naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com